# I AM WOKEN UP. Could i use "woken" here as an adjective/state instead of passive voice

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, british-english, adjective-phrases, participial-adjectives

I have not used "I am woken up" here as in passive voice but I have used "woken" as an adjective here and more or less the sentence is reffering to the state as in i woke up/i have woken up.
I want to ask if this sentence is correct grammatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "woken" cannot be used that way.

You're trying to use the participle "woken" as an attributive adjective, similar to:

- *the sleeping child*
- *the painted wall*
- *the ruined building*

Not all participles can form attributive adjectives. "Woken" cannot.

We can, however, use "awakened", though it tends to have a figurative meaning, as in, *becoming aware of* something, rather than waking up from sleep.

Comment: and how about awoken as an adjective "I am awoken" as in "I have awoken"/I am no longer a sleep now

Answer (score 2):

It's 'grammatically correct', but it doesn't mean what you think. If you want to say that you are no longer asleep, say *I am awake* (or, as you suggest, *I have woken up*).

*I am woken up* would mean 'someone wakes me up' (assuming you are telling a story in the present tense).

Comment: and how about awoken as an adjective "I am awoken" as in "I have awoken"/I am no longer a sleep now 

–

Comment: _Awoken_ is a past participle. [This](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awoken) gives one or two examples of it being used as an adjective, but as a learner of English I would strongly recommend you to stick to **awake**